# Project Structure in MS Visual Code as Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, project-structure

I'm trying to open a python project in Visual Code but I get an error on importing files "file not found". In Pycharm it is possible to edit the Project Structure and add files as "sources". How is it possible in Vscode?

I have tried to add folders to the workspace in File > Add folder to the workspace.

I do not have any code for doind this. The project works fine in Pycharm but in vscode.

Comment: Have you found the answer for this?

Comment: @user1394 Read my answe below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to write my solution, This is what I did.

1. Open the folder where you have your files
2. Save the workspace
3. Open Launch.json and edit it like following:

   ```
   { // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
   // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
   // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
       {
           "name": "Python: Current File",
           "type": "python",
           "request": "launch",
           "program": "${file}",
           "console": "integratedTerminal",
           "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
           "env": {
               "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}\\folder1; 
                              ${workspaceFolder}\\folder2\\dada;
                              ${workspaceFolder}\\folder3\\dadadsada "
           }
       }
   ]}
   ```

Now I only need to go to Debug > Run without Debugging and it works.